# how do I resolve dependency error => Net is not missing constant HTTPResponse

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler

I did a no-no: I blindly did a `bundle update` without saving my previous configuration.  Now when I call Mechanize's get(), I get the following error message from activesupport.  I've included the backtrace to make it clear what versions are involved.

Have I messed up the dependencies somehow?  What's the best way to resolve this?

```
ArgumentError: Net is not missing constant HTTPResponse!
from /sandbox/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:479:in `load_missing_constant'
from /sandbox/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:183:in `block in const_missing'
from /sandbox/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:181:in `each'
from /sandbox/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:181:in `const_missing'
from /sandbox/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-http-persistent-2.3.2/lib/net/http/persistent/ssl_reuse.rb:66:in `connect'
from /sandbox/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:637:in `do_start'
from /sandbox/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:632:in `start'
from /sandbox/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-http-persistent-2.3.2/lib/net/http/persistent.rb:582:in `reset'
from /sandbox/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-http-persistent-2.3.2/lib/net/http/persistent.rb:397:in `connection_for'
from /sandbox/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-http-persistent-2.3.2/lib/net/http/persistent.rb:616:in `request'
from /sandbox/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mechanize-2.1/lib/mechanize/http/agent.rb:264:in `fetch'
from /sandbox/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mechanize-2.1/lib/mechanize.rb:319:in `get'
```

Comment: FWIW, I realize I do have archived copies of Gemfile.lock -- I don't know if that will help me back out of this morass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved.  This was due to a short-lived bug in Mechanize that @drbrain quickly fixed.  His answer:

> Upgrade to net-http-persistent 2.3.3, there was a bug. See drbrain/net-http-persistent@3fadf4a for the fix.)